Trac Wiki: Can links shown in 'Search' be customized?
The Trac wiki search shows results as links with a short summary.
A recent rework of our wiki has unintentionally broken this summary.
Meaning all pages now start with a paragraph of boilerplate which consists of a table and a long breadcrumb path.
Is there any way to customize the summary that is shown?
I would like to make a summary that skips the table.
